# Lost mobile data connection upon Android 11 minor upgrade - from Sep 1, 2021 to Nov 1, 2021 - APN menu gone - Motorola moto g 5G

Tags: connection-issues, mobile-data, google-play-services, mobile-network, motorola

My Motorola moto g 5G was updated to Android 11 with Android security update Sep 1 2021 a few weeks ago. Everything worked fine until a few days ago when there was a seemingly minor update to Android security update Nov 1 2021.

Then **I lost all mobile data connectivity.**  Mobile calls as well as Wi-Fi data do work as expected.  Several reboots and checks also via menu `*#*#4634#*#*` seem to indicate working data connectivity to me.  The mobile data symbol "4G" is visible but greyed out, indicating working but deactivated mobile data connectivity - same as when connected to Wi-Fi.  My carrier said that everything is fine on their side.

Also, at the same time the problem started a menu item / sub-menu was lost:

```
Settings -> Network&internet -> Mobile network
```

The menu shows the SIM card and a "Use SIM" slider switch (active) but there are no options underneath.   There *used to be* an "Advanced" option with Access Point Names.  That option is gone - therefore I could not check and/or re-set APNs to try to solve the issue.

**How can I re-activate the connection to mobile data?  Is perhaps some new Google app necessary to switch to mobile data?**  The phone has Google Play Services disabled (worked well with Android 10 and 11 for several months).

This update also brought a new "WiFi calling" icon in the top notification bar (visible whenever I am connected to Wi-Fi).  There is no Wi-Fi problem, though.  I am just saying this for knowledgeable people to know which software development level I am at.  Perhaps some other, mobile data relevant change was introduced at the same time as Wi-Fi calling was?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the SIM, reboot and reinsert the SIM card (and again reboot)?

Comment: Thanks @Robert , doing it right now. Shall I re-insert the SIM card while the mobile is on?

Comment: Usually inserting a SIM card, while the phone is on, is allowed. Some phones automatically perform a reboot after inserting.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, no effect. Menu still lost and mobile data switched off though 4G-connected, data enabled and Wi-Fi off.